# how node handles computation and event loop

Tags: node.js, event-loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++){ 
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Inside")
    }, 0);
    console.log("Outside") 
};
```

It gives the output:

Outside * 100000

Inside * 100000

why this output?

CPU bound activities are handled in-line, and when all CPU bound activities are over then it processes the event que?

Comment: JavaScript has a "run to completion" mechanism where it will complete all code in the current task before polling the event queue. `setTimeout` pushes to the event queue. You are pushing 100000 messages to the event queue, but none of them are run until the current block (the for loop where you are also printing 100000 times) completes.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` is non-blocking and it calls it's callback asynchronously.  That means that `setTimeout()` runs, schedules a timer for the future and then immediately returns.  Then, sometime later, when the timer fires, it inserts an event in the event queue.  When the interpreter is done executing other Javascript, it fetches the next event out of the event queue and will then run the timer callback.

So, here's what happens in your code:

1. Run the body of the `for` loop 100,000 times and each time through the loop, schedule a timer and then output `console.log("Outside")`.
2. Then, when the `for` loop is done and control returns back to the system, check the event queue to see if there is an event.
3. Because all the timers were set with a timer of `0`, there are probably a lot of timer events in the queue.  Pull the first event out and runs it's callback which will output `console.log("Inside")`.
4. Repeat until there are no more events in the event queue (which will take 100,000 iterations to process all the timers you previously set).

There are two keys here:

1. `setTimeout()` is "non-blocking".  It schedules the timer and immediately returns.
2. When the timer fires, it inserts an event in the event queue to run the timer callback and that callback will ONLY get called when the JS interpreter is done doing what else it was doing and can then fetch the next event from the event queue.

This means that all synchronous code finishes first before any asynchronous callbacks can be fetched from the event queue and run.